# Understanding Package Ancestry

Tags: salesforcedx

Looking at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_config_ancestors.htm, I have some questions.

"*When you create a scratch org, any ancestors defined for a package version that you include in the sfdx-project.json file are automatically added to the scratch org. You can exclude the ancestors by using the --noancestors option when you create a scratch org with force:org:create*"

I am not clear on this point.

But why would I care about previous package versions being added to scratch org as long as I have the version I want on it?

Is it just to keep the versioning clean ? Is it to keep the code at the package level away cleaner?  Usually deprecated functionality is just removed from version control and a new version released. I am having a hard time coming up with a use case that explains the benefit of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has two benefits. First, it allows you to set up a new environment that's based on a specific package version, versus whatever might be in your current working tree. For example, you might have stuff in your working tree that may not compile with force:source:push, but working off a specific ancestor guarantees the metadata is in a deployable state. Secondly, if you need to abandon a branch and move to an earlier state, this feature can help make sure you have the correct metadata to move forward from. If you're not developing a package, or you have an alternative strategy, then there's no reason for you to take advantage of this. It just happens to be a feature you can take advantage of if you'd like.